# Add Cookie in Bootstrap collapsible sidebar navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
          <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav navbar-nav" id="sidebar">
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle brd-top" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="EAI System">EAI System<i class="fa fa-desktop sub_icon"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate relative" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#" title="Service Catalog">Service Catalog<i class="fa fa-cogs sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="Environment">Environment<i class="fa fa-cloud sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="Onboarding Checklist">Onboarding Checklist<i class="fa fa-list-alt sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="Active Userlist">Active Userlist<i class="fa fa-user sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle brd-top" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="EAI Troubleshooting">EAI Troubleshooting<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle sub_icon"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate relative" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="dashboard.html" title="Troubleshooting">Troubleshooting<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle brd-top" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="EAI Deployment">EAI Deployment<i class="fa fa-share sub_icon"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate relative" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#" title="Deployment Log">Deployment Log<i class="fa fa-check-square-o sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#" title="Test Results">Test Results<i class="fa fa-server sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle brd-top" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" title="EAI Reports">EAI Reports<i class="fa fa-line-chart sub_icon"></i></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate relative" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#" title="Reports">Reports<i class="fa fa-line-chart sub_icon"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This bootstrap menu in master page. My Problem is when i click on any collapse and click on link. Next page open with open collapse panel.

Comment: Are you using twitter bootstrap?

Comment: i am using bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Despite it's not preferred to use jquery in Angular, as stated in [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) you can use:

```
$('#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1').collapse('hide')
```

to hide collapsed menu. 
You can do this in new view controller on load.